# commit a git repository into a git repository

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration

I'm not looking to implement sub-modules. I'm writing code which wraps and manipulates git repositories.

I want to test this code and I don't want the build system to have to fetch build resources from the network so despite the fact that the artifacts are binary (they are tiny) I still want to check them into (in raw form) my project repository.

I've created two repositories for testing, one 'good' (the code will build) and one 'bad' (the code will fail to build).

The thing is git refuses to commit them verbatim, it seems to create 'gitlinks' instead.

Any way to achieve this?